# Making a well conditioned orthonormal basis

Tags: matrices, statistics

Ok, so I have n dependent gaussian random variables that are related by a known n x n covariance matrix.

What I would like to do, is produce a linear transformation to turn them into n independent random variables which are all of variance 1. Now, that alone is easy. what I could do, is just Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization; for the first one, I just divide the random variable by the square root of its variance (its standard deviation) and that's orthonormal component #1. Then do the same thing with the second variable, but then subtract its correlation with the first random variable times the first random variable, and then normalize it to have a variance of 1 again. And so on and so forth.

BUT the first component I produce will be - for lack of a better description - better conditioned - than the second. And it only gets worse and worse with each additional component. And I mean the same sense of the term as in how well conditioned a matrix is. Each time, I'm subtracting random variables from other random variables, and the errors due to limitations of measurement of the random variables are amplified more and more due to the subtraction errors of taking off the components of all the previously defined orthonormal components. Rather than the first orthonormal component being really well conditioned and each one following getting crummier and crummier, do you know a way to produce an orthonormal basis so that they are all equally crummy. Or minimally crummy on average mayhaps I should say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the $n$-dimensional column vector $X$ is (jointly) Gaussian with covariance matrix $C$, 
for any fixed $n \times n$ matrix $A$, $AX$ is Gaussian with covariance 
$A C A^T$.  So all you need is $A = C^{-1/2}$, i.e. the positive semidefinite
square root of $C^{-1}$.

Comment: Hmm, well, that would produce ONE set of independent unity variance gaussians, but is it the best one for minimizing the effects of errors?

Comment: I realize now your way isn't just A way of doing it, it's the ONLY way of doing it, because it's a different problem than making an orthonormal set because it's a quadratic transformation of the covariance matrix - I also can see that I can just keep the positive eigenvalues pretty easily this way - with D^-.5*Q, where D^-.5 is a square matrix of just the eigenvalues I want to keep to the -.5 power, and Q's rows are the corresponding eigenvectors, and then I transform it into just the number of free variables I really had to work with from the original random variables. Thanks.

Comment: Not **quite** the only way of doing it: $A C A^T = I$ is equivalent to $A = U C^{-1/2}$ where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. But that has the same condition number (for the Euclidean norm) as $C^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I am running into some problems with my little extension of the solution you gave me, my extension for dealing with negative eigenvalues that is. I posted it as a separate question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514118/mysterious-failure-to-generate-independent-set-of-random-variables if you are still monitoring this for comment replies, I hope you might consider taking a look. Thanks. I wonder if what you said about multiplying it by an orthogonal matrix might be something that could solve it, though I doubt that, that would just entail a rotation, correct?